# Add a checkbox to WooCommerce's My account "Account details"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailchimp, account

In WooCommerce My account > Account details section, I have been able to add a checkbox with the following code:

```
<div class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide woocommerce-form-row-newsletter">
    <label for="account_email" class="checkboxLabel"><?php esc_html_e( 'Receive Timenaut newsletter', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-settings">
        <?php
        woocommerce_form_field( 'mc4wp-subscribe', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('form-row-wide')
            ), $value = 1);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've added this to form-edit-account.php, the checkbox is displayed properly, but as obvious it's not saving the value.

How can I save the checkbox value properly?

---

Now I would like also to add the subscriber to a MailChimp list.

Do you know any way to send it to Mailchimp without any plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your checkbox working on My account > Account details section and save the value, You can use the following:

```
// Remove "(optional)" label for this checkbox
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    if( 'mc4wp-subscribe' === $key ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// Display a custom checkbox in My Account > Account details
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'display_edit_account_checkbox_field' );
function display_edit_account_checkbox_field() {
    woocommerce_form_field( 'mc4wp-subscribe', array(
        'type'  => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __( 'Receive Timenaut newsletter', 'woocommerce' ),
        'clear' => true,
    ), get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'mc4wp-subscribe', true ) );

}

// Save checkbox field value for My Account > Account details
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_checkbox_value_to_account_details', 10, 1 );
function save_checkbox_value_to_account_details( $user_id ) {
    $value = isset( $_POST['mc4wp-subscribe'] ) ? '1' : '0';
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mc4wp-subscribe', $value );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and work.

> Now to register/unregister the subscriber in Mailchimp is another question and **the rule on Stack OverFlow is one question at the time**. So you will have to ask a new question for that.

Comment: What if you want to add this checkbox to the registration form as well? What should we do for that?